# What is the probability that two even-numbered chips are drawn and they occur on even-numbered draws?

Tags: probability

> A bowl contains ten chips numbered $1,2,...,10$, respectively. Five chips are drawn at random, one at a time, and without replacement. What is the probability that two even-numbered chips are drawn and they occur on even-numbered draws?

I think the answer could be $\frac{5}{10}\frac{5}{9}\frac{4}{8}\frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{6}=\frac{5}{14}$ but I'm not sure, could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you mean "exactly two even-numbered chips"  then your answer is correct! But it is not $\frac{5}{14}$ because it's $\frac{5}{126}$

Comment: I believe what @LucaMac meant to say is that the expression on the left-hand side of your equation is correct if you meant exactly two even-numbered chips but the expression evaluates to $\frac{5}{126}$ rather than $\frac{5}{14}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $abcde$ be the positions of the $5$ chips, so the even number drawn chips can appear only on the $b$ and $d$ positions. There are only $5$ even numbers among those on the chips.

The probability will be $\dfrac {\binom 5 1} {\binom {10} 1}$ multiplied by $\dfrac {\binom 5 1} {\binom 9 1}$ (because this position is even number position so chip will be drawn from even number of chips) multiplied by $\dfrac {\binom 4 1} {\binom 8 1}$ (odd number position) multiplied by $\dfrac {\binom 4 1} {\binom 7 1}$ (even number position) multiplied by $\dfrac {\binom 3 1} {\binom 6 1}$, which is indeed $\dfrac {5 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3} {10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).